# PHPUnit ignores DB_CONNECTION variable in phpunit.xml file in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, testing, phpunit

Everything was fine until yesterday when PHPUnit for no reason stoped seeing `DB_CONNECTION` environment variable from `phpunit.xml` file and started taking it from `.env` file.

I tried to recreate `phpunit.xml` file, clear all possible caches - no result.

This is my `phpunit.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Modules Tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./Modules/**/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Tests\DatabaseTestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true" processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./Modules</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix="blade.php">./Modules</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Routes</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Resources</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Tests</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Config</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="tests/coverage" showUncoveredFiles="true" />
    </logging>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="./database/database.sqlite"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

This is my `config/database.php` file:

```php
    'connections' => [
        'sqlite_testing' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
        ...
    ]
```

Of courses file `database/database.sqlite` exists.

And when I try to get driver name in my test:

```php
public function test_some(): void
{
    dd(\DB::getDriverName());
}
```

I get:
[image]

Comment: Set everything that is `<server` inside your `<php>` to be `<env`, else it will not be replaced by `phpunit.xml` (if found on `.env`). Then, do you ONLY have `.env` or do you also have `.env.testing`? Are you running this using `php artisan test` or `./vendor/bin/phpunit` or are you using a CI/CD tool like CircleCI or GithubActions or Bitbucket Pipelines?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I run it using `./vendor/bin/phpunit` and using internal PHPStorm instruments. And I have only `.env`, no `.env.testing`

Comment: @matiaslauriti added `.env.testing`, replaced all `<server` with `<env` inside `phpunit.xml`, ran `./vendor/bin/phpunit` and `php artisan test` - same story.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache && composer dump-autoload` solved it... I don't know how and why

Comment: No need to add `.env.testing`, what that will do is, if you have `.env` and `.env.testing`, it will load `.env.testing` and use what you have defined in there. Check that you don't have `DB_CONNECTION` in there or just remove the file if you truly not need it, also, just in case, run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Of course... NEVER cache the config locally... NEVER run `php artisan config:cache`, because you have a local config that will not LOAD any ENV...

Comment: @matiaslauriti ouch, didn't know it. Thank you so much! You may answer this question, I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

matiaslauriti:

"Of course... NEVER cache the config locally... NEVER run php artisan config:cache, because you have a local config that will not LOAD any ENV..."

So `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && composer dump-autoload` solved the problem